# Test Automation for USB communication between android USB host and printer

Tags: android, testing, automation, usb, thermal-printer

I've an android application that sends the data to the printer  and printer sends some commands back to the android host over USB. I need to automate the testing to verify if the communication is happened properly between the android usb host and the printer.
    Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for this you will need a automation testing tool which does those checks in the background for you. i recommend using a very good automation testing Tool called  "TestComplete" by smartbear. they have added good support for android and ios testing. just have a look.

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/57760

here you go, hope this helps